# The limit of $(x^2-\tan 2x)/\tan x$ as $x\to0$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I'm stuck in finding the following limit:

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\left(x^2-\tan\left(2x\right)\right)}{\tan\left(x\right)}\right)$$

I am not sure how to do this one help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\tan(2x)=\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x},$$
we have$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2-\tan(2x)}{\tan x}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{\tan x}-\frac{2\tan x}{\tan x(1-\tan^2x)}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}x\cos x\cdot \frac{1}{(\sin x/x)}-\frac{2}{1-\tan ^2x}\\&=0\cdot 1\cdot \frac 11-\frac{2}{1-0}\\&=-2.\end{align}$$

Comment: thats nice Patricia

Answer (score 0):

If the usage of [Series expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html) is allowed,

$$\tan y=y+\frac{y^3}3+\frac{2y^5}{15}+\cdots$$

Comment: use the rules of L'Hospital you will get $-2$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, Here also, we find $$\frac{-2}1$$

Comment: yes indeed we find the searched limit

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x^2-\tan2x}{\tan x}$$
$$=\frac1{1-\tan^2x}\cdot\frac{x^2(1-\tan^2x)-2\tan x}{\tan x}$$

$$=\frac1{1-\tan^2x}\cdot\frac{x(1-\tan^2x)-2\dfrac{\tan x}x}{\dfrac{\tan x}x}$$

dividing the numerator & the denominator by $x$ 
as $x\ne0$ as $x\to0$

Now apply the limit

Answer (score 0):

=$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\left(x^2-tan\left(2x\right)\right)}{tan\left(x\right)}\right)$

=$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\left(x^2-tan\left(2x\right)\right)}{x}\cdot \frac{x}{tan\left(x\right)}\right)$

=$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\left(x^{ }-\frac{tan\left(2x\right)}{x}\right)\cdot \frac{x}{tan\left(x\right)}\right)$

=$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\left(x^{ }-\frac{2\cdot tan\left(2x\right)}{2\cdot x}\right)\cdot \frac{x}{tan\left(x\right)}\right)$

=$-2\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{tan\left(2x\right)}{2x}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{tan\left(x\right)}{x}\right)}$

=-2

Answer (score 0):

You could use $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-\tan 2x}{\tan x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-\frac{\sin 2x}{\cos 2x}}{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\cos 2x-\sin 2x}{\sin x}\cdot\frac{\cos x}{\cos 2x}$

$\;\;\;\;\;\displaystyle=\lim_{x\to0}\bigg(x\cdot\frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot\cos 2x-2\cos x\bigg)\cdot\frac{\cos x}{\cos 2x}$.